# reshape a dataframe with internal headers as new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame as below :

```
             col          value
0      companyId         123456
1   company_name  small company
2     department             IT
3  employee_name           Jack
4           rank        Grade 8
5     department        finance
6  employee_name            Tim
7           rank        Grade 6
```

and i would like the data frame to be reshaped to tabular format, ideally like this:

```
  companyId   company_name department employee_name     rank
0    123456  small company         IT          Jack  Grade 8
1    123456  small company    finance           Tim  Grade 6
```

can any one help me please? thanks.

Comment: How do you know the employee `Tim` is belong to the same company with `Jack`, I mean, maybe another `comanyId` in this data frame too?

Answer (score 1):

Making two assumptions you could reshape your data.

1- the companies are determined using headers and all subsequent rows are data from employees of the company

2- there is a given starting item to define employees records (here department)

```
headers = ['companyId', 'company_name']
first_item = 'department'

masks = {h: df['col'].eq(h) for h in headers}

df2 = (df
  # move headers as new columns
 .assign(**{h: df['value'].where(m).ffill().bfill() for h,m in masks.items()})
  # and drop their rows
 .loc[~pd.concat(masks, axis=1).any(1)]
  # compute a unique identifier per employee
 .assign(idx=lambda d: d['col'].eq(first_item).cumsum())
  # pivot the data
 .pivot(index=['idx']+headers, columns='col', values='value')
 .reset_index(headers)
)
```

output:

```
  companyId   company_name department employee_name     rank
1    123456  small company         IT          Jack  Grade 8
2    123456  small company    finance           Tim  Grade 6
```

Example on a more complex input:

```
              col          value
0       companyId         123456
1    company_name  small company
2      department             IT
3   employee_name           Jack
4            rank        Grade 8
5      department        finance
6   employee_name            Tim
7            rank        Grade 6
8       companyId          67890
9    company_name  other company
10     department             IT
11  employee_name           Jane
12           rank        Grade 9
13     department     management
14  employee_name           Tina
15           rank       Grade 12
```

output:

```
  companyId   company_name  department employee_name      rank
1    123456  small company          IT          Jack   Grade 8
2    123456  small company     finance           Tim   Grade 6
3     67890  other company          IT          Jane   Grade 9
4     67890  other company  management          Tina  Grade 12
```